# adobe cq5 display thumbnail from the uploaded smart image

Tags: adobe, thumbnails, aem

I'm building a custom component in CQ5 and I faced with some issues.

The idea is:

- In a paragraph system custom components called `imageItem` to be added.
- Each `ImageItem` is consisted of image and it's thumbnail (autogenerated).
- In order to drag and drop the gallery image into `galleryitem` component I'm using the cq5 smartimage component on the first tab.
- On the second tab I want to show the preview of the thumbnail of the dragged image 
  (saying that the thumbnails are auto-generated while uploading image as resource and can be accessed adding the following path to the original image url: {image_url}.thumb.100.100.jpg)

Is there any cq5 component that can display those images for the following url?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about doing all of this within the component's dialog --

If you just want to show an image in a dialog without providing all the editing capabilities that xtype `smartimage` gives you, you can use a [label widget](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Label) with the `html` property set to:

```
<img src="{your-thumbnail-image-path}" />
```

Now, since you want that to match whatever image you have loaded in your `smartimage` on the other tab, you'll want to set up a listener on the `smartimage` to update your `label`'s html whenever you change the image in the first tab.

To see an example of some out-of-the-box dialog listeners, take a look at the list component's dialog in CRXDE Lite at

```
/libs/foundation/components/list/dialog/items/list/items/listFrom/listeners
```

In your case, you'll probably want to listen for the `imagestate` event (found in the events section of the [API docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartImage)), and when it fires you'll want to do something like this:

```js
function(smartImg) {
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog'),
        label = dialog.find('name', 'thumbnailPreviewLabel')[0];

    label.update('<img src="' + smartImg.referencedFileInfo.dataPath + '.thumb.100.100.jpg" />');
}
```

where `thumbnailPreviewLabel` is the name attribute for your `label` widget.

For this example I took a few shortcuts like defining the listener inline in the dialog.xml (which is a little ugly because of the escaped HTML characters - you'll probably want to define the function in a separate javascript file and just use it by name here), and I used the raw path to a DAM rendition since the thumbnail servlet wasn't working for me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="Image Thumbnail Preview"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <image
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                cropParameter="./imageCrop"
                ddGroups="[media]"
                fileNameParameter="./fileName"
                fileReferenceParameter="./fileReference"
                mapParameter="./imageMap"
                name="./file"
                requestSuffix=".img.png"
                rotateParameter="./imageRotate"
                title="Image"
                xtype="html5smartimage">
                <listeners
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    imagestate="function(smartImg) { this.findParentByType('dialog').find('name', 'thumbnailPreviewLabel')[0].update('&lt;img src=&quot;' + smartImg.referencedFileInfo.dataPath + '/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png&quot; /&gt;'); }"/>
            </image>
            <preview
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                anchor="100%"
                title="Image Thumbnail Preview"
                xtype="panel">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <thumbnail
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        name="thumbnailPreviewLabel"
                        html=""
                        xtype="label"/>
                </items>
            </preview>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```